# change some field type cause exception when access the database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I change some field from `char(50)` to be `VARCHAR(MAX)`. 
I did this change from the visual studio.

Now, i trying to access to the database and i get the exception

> Cannot open user default database.
>   Login failed. Login failed for user
>   'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.

my knowledge on sql is very pure - and i dont know how to solve this problem.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251839/login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-network-service)  - and still nothing work fine.

Thanks for any help.

**Update**: I reverse the change that i made thru the visual studio - and all work fine. 
I made the change in same way and the exception appear again.

Is there some other way to do this simple change ?

Comment: Are you connecting to SQL from a web app?

Comment: It's a bit of a guess but I doubt the two are connected. What application/process is causing the login failure. Is it your application or Sql Server Management Studio for example?

Comment: OK , So i developing WCF server application. When i run the server i get the exception ( only on runtime ).

Comment: I using Linq to SQL to make my sql read/write. this is something that work fine before my field change ( char(50) to be VARCHAR(MAX)) and i did not change anything beside this.

Comment: ALTER TABLE xyz ALTER COLUMN abc VARCHAR(MAX) BUT this shouldn't affect the connection to the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically because your WCF server app runs under the network service account it cannot use windows authentication to connect to SQL. Can you not use SQL username and password as the connection string?

Comment: Im not using username & password on my connection string. I have simple .mdf file that i connect with - and i just using the linq to get the data ( read / write ).