# Login failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005

I have created a windows service & my service is dependent on the SQL server service. First, SQL started and then my service started when starting PC or restarting PC.

This works fine but the issue is database file can not be read by the Windows service, throwing the exception "Cannot open user default database. Login failed.Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' " when i am trying to read the database.

If I start the computer & login then it can not read the database, but if i have start the computer & wait for a few seconds and then log into the window service it reads the database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251839/login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-network-service

Comment: try this one http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/20/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authoritynetwork-service/

Answer (score 33):

I bet you have this in your connection string:

```
Integrated Security=SSPI
```

or something similar.

Now the account that service is running under (`NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`) tries to connect to the database - and can't since it's not authorized to do so.

You can:

- either create a login for `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` in your SQL Server and give it the necessary permissions it needs for your app

OR:

- you create a specific application user account in SQL Server (login to SQL Server and user in your database) and change your connection string to:

  ```
  User ID=(your app account);pwd=YourPassword
  ```

Comment: string conString = "Data Source = .\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName = " + Path.path + "; Integrated Security =true;Connect Timeout=1000"

Comment: @user847455: yes that's what I thought - Integrated Security. I mentioned possible solutions above - pick one

Comment: I picked your first option. This code adds the permission:

`var process = new Process();
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = "/C sqlcmd -S .\\SQLEXPRESS -Q \"sp_addsrvrolemember NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM\""
    };

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();`

Answer (score 8):

Go to security tab under your database.

Under `security`, Click to expand the `Users` tab.

**Find weather `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` is present.**

If not, **Right click on users**, Click on **new user**

In new user window, `general` tab change the `user type` to **windows user**.

Select the User name to, NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM you will have to find it in the `Advanced tab, find now, and select system`.

Similarly for login name, `browse and find NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`.

And in the membership tab to the left, select all the required boxes and click ok.

Probably this would fix your issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: Security->Logins: select `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`  Login Properties -> User Mapping and then you can add the database(s) you want to give permissions to, and set role membership for this user. Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

I removed `Trusted_Connection=yes` from connection string and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I actually just changed the permissions for the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM user in SQL Server and this worked for me.

Comment: Which permission? I have already enabled "sysadmin" and "public"

Comment: upvote because i had to add the user role and add the permissions.. but this helped me...

Comment: What permissions for NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM were changed exactly? And how do you change these permissions

Answer (score 1):

you can add this on Connection string

persist security info=True

Answer (score -2):

The simple solution is to check your `web.config` file and make sure one of these is part of the database connection string:

```
Trusted Connection=false
```

OR

```
Integrated Security=True
```

Comment: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'trusted connection'.

Comment: This is not a simple solution this is exactly the problem of the thread opener... that he has Integrated Security=true