# Classic ASP, IIS 5.1, errors logging in to SQL Server using Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server-2005, iis, asp-classic

I'm trying to setup a test environment on my own machine, of our company website written in classic asp. The idea is to use integrated windows authentication to connect to the database.

I'm useing the following connection string

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Server=localhost;Database=Filbert;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

But the browser responds with

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server (0x80004005)
[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
```

In the SQL log I can see

```
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 16.
```

A state 16 errors is whe

I'm running Windows XP SP3, IIS 5.1, SQL server 2005

EDIT: I've also created and tested an login using SQL authentication instead. I'm able to login with the SQL authentication using the SQL management studio just fine, but get the same errors when trying from ASP

Comment: Did you check that SYSTEM actually has access to that database? It's not that SYSTEM automatically can do everything.

Comment: Side node: You should definitely not run your web site in the local system context. Create a dedicated, low privilege account for IIS and grant that account access to the database.

Comment: The SQL server has a login for the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account, with access to the database.

Comment: The low-priveledge account seems to be a feature of iis 6, which unfortunately for me doesn't exist for winxp. Otherwise I would have followed this [guide](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/)

Comment: You can run IIS5 under a different service account (Services control panel). I'm sorry but *"Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'"* is pretty unambiguous. It is a plain and simple access denied message, you must double-check your SQL server login configuration. Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6894702/18771) which comes to the same conclusion.

Comment: The 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' account is also something that confuses me. Even though I've changed my connection string to use SQL authentication, the login still fails and the user is still NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM in the sql log.

Comment: My course of action would be to first switch IIS to a dedicated, non-privileged account (create a standard user). Then allow that account in SQL Server. Then try again with SQL Native Client and integrated security. `Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=localhost;Database=Filbert;Trusted_Connection=yes;`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a specific user in SQL server, test the connection to the db with that user and then in your asp code do the following

```
<%
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=YourPassword;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=YourUserID;_
       Initial Catalog=YourDB;Data Source=YOUR_LOCAL_SERVER_NAME

 Set commInsert = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 commInsert.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;_
     PersistSecurity Info=False;Initial Catalog=_
     YourDB;_Data Source=YOUR_LOCAL_SERVER_NAME

 'now you can eg do an insert
 strInsertCommand = "INSERT INTO tableName(TextField, NumericField)_
     VALUES('ABCDE', 12345);"
 commInsert.Execute(strInsertCommand) ' Execute the insert command
 commInsert.Close()
 Set commInsert = Nothing
 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix the problem by switching the SQL provider to SQLNCLI

```
Provider=SQL;Server=localhost;Database=Filbert;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```