# IIS Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: sql-server, security, iis-6

I have a iis6 box with that app pool configured to use an Active Directory service account.

I'm running an classic asp app, and I want to use the service account to connect to the database, so I have this as my connection string: "provider=SQLOLEDB.1;server=myserver;database=mydb;Integrated Security=SSPI"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894651/login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-system