# SQL Server Login error: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'

Tags: sql-server, iis, authentication

I have created an application pool called "schoolPool" and assigned it to my web application. Identity for this pool has been set to LocalSystem. 
When I try to access my database from within the application, i.e. open a SQL connection, I get the following error all the time:

```
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'
```

I tried to add NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM to SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) logins, but it was already a principal, showing the following error: 
[image]

Comment: Old now, but it needs to be said that it's a **VERY BAD IDEA** to run your web app as local system. Any compromise of the app, no matter how small, now immediately  also grants full admin access on the machine.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I tweaked the application settings a lot, changing the application pool's identity (in Windows 8.1's IIS) to LocalSystem, LocalService, NetworkService, and ApplicationPoolIdentity. However, all of them failed to solve the problem I had logging into my database. 

**Finally** I set the pool identity on LocalSystem and thought why it might be preventing "NT AUTHRITY\SYSTEM" from opening a connection to my database. I opened up SQL Server Management Studio as "Administrator" and checked the **Server Roles**  for NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM under "logins" section. The default server role for this user was *public* by default. **I also checked sysadmin**  and refreshed my web application form. This time it worked! Everything working perfectly now.

Comment: This is the only thing that works. Change the app pool to the local system and then add the sysadmin to that user in DB.

Answer (score 145):

Allow NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM to server Role as sysadmin.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What if NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM doesn't exist?  I manually created it but still get the same error.

Comment: @Steve Smith link help to set NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894651/login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-system

Comment: In some cases, you need to go to 'User Mapping' and check(select) the database and be sure about the user there.

Answer (score 6):

There is another fix. You should open Command Prompt (cmd) and write the following:

> sqlcmd -S (server name)

```
select name from sys.server_principals where name = 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'

go

SP_ADDSRVROLEMEMBER 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM','SYSADMIN'

go
```

The first line will give you an access to the sql server on you machine, the second will
take the following result `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` an the stored procedure `addsrvrolemember` will add `sysadmin` to it. Be careful, because you have to type the following code the way it is.

Answer (score 3):

Rerun following query which will assign 'NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER' to sysadmin

```
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER', @rolename = N'sysadmin'
```

Comment: thanks, EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember "@loginame" = N'NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM', "@rolename" = N'sysadmin'

Answer (score 2):

Musakkhir's answer of granting sysadmin seems poorly thought out as far as security goes, and Pinal's answer involved giving the unknown process db_owner rights, still almost certainly overkill. I've 'solved' it myself by simply granting "public" rights, which normally just allows CONNECT, but nothing else, even SELECT. If gets rid of the login error and stops flooding the error log, since it now logs in, but whatever unknown process is doing the connecting still can't do anything.

Comment: You should probably use SQL Server Profiler to identify the process that is connecting, rather than granting permissions, if that is what you are concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

You should give your User ID and pwd of SQL server authentication login in the connectionStrings as User ID="username";pwd="yourpassword". You can use the following query
CREATE LOGIN login name WITH PASSWORD = 'password' ;
GO

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the procedure: After database login- Security --> Logins --> NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (right click to Properties) --> Server Roles --> sysadmin (Checked)