# Login failed for user NT Authority\System

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, iis, windows-server-2008

I have **ASP.NET MVC** app that connects to **MSSQL** database on **Windows Server 2008 R2**. The thing is that I see this error and can't solve the problem:

```
Login failed for user NT Authority\System
```

- I have created login under SQL Server for NT Authority\System and gave sysadmin access to my database (+ selected default database)
- Application pool uses LocalSystem user
- Firewall is turned off

What may be a reason of my problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Login error: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822076/sql-server-login-error-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-system)

Comment: It isn't duplicate since that answer doesn't for me..

Comment: Is the database on the same machine as the web server?

Comment: Yeah, answer below solves my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run the application pool under a custom account (Windows admin for me)

[image]