# Cannot open database requested by the login. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. Quartz Scheduler Windows Services

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-services, database-connection, quartz.net

Have my service set to login using 'Local System Account' with 'Allow service to interact with desktop' ticked.

Here's my C# connection string which works allowing interaction with DB when I execute the application outside of the Quartz/Windows Service:

```
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="ArbDBConnStr"
      connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Arb-20160906102730;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

What do I have to do to enable the the windows service to be able to access the db?

---

UPDATES - STILL NO JOY
[image]

[image]

Also no info in SQL Server logs that I can see that would shed any light - what should I be seeing?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this: [SQL Server Login error: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822076/sql-server-login-error-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-system). Try some of the suggested answers.

Comment: thanks tried the suggestion adding sys admin but still no joy. However, saw this error in event viewer - not sure if this could have anything to do with it and not sure how - if necessary - to fix it either:-----------

The service is marked as an interactive service. However, the system is configured to not allow interactive services. This service may not function properly.

Comment: Looks like that is nothing to worry about but also noticed this:-------------------------
The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{8D8F4F83-3594-4F07-8369-FC3C3CAE4919}
 and APPID 
{F72671A9-012C-4725-9D2F-2A4D32D65169}
 to the user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM SID (S-1-5-18) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

Comment: For the interactive service error, try the 'Resolve' solution from [Event ID 7030 — Basic Service Operations](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756339(v=ws.10).aspx) while your service is running.

Comment: For the second one, follow the steps here: [error: “The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation “](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mutaz/2009/02/11/error-the-application-specific-permission-settings-do-not-grant-local-activation/).

Comment: It seems very unlikely that you need to set the "allow service to interact with desktop" option.  That's long-deprecated functionality.

Comment: yes ignoring that - just going through everything. No joy yet. Will keep digging. thank you all. For the second error above I dont have the  IIS WAMREG admin service referred to in the link.

Comment: Have you looked in the SQL logs to determine the cause of the logon failure?

Comment: Please see updates:
- Have set User 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' Server Roles to sysadmin as well as public and have mapped 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' to the DB with db_owner and public role membership all displayed in images above. Also included SQL Server Logs which seem to be unhelpful - what should I be expecting to see that could help pinpoint the problem?

Comment: @user6063812 I have the same problem an i am going crazy. None of the recommended fixes help. Did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with this issue what i did was simply :

1. Open SSMS --> Security --> Logins --> 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'
2. Right-click --> Properties
3. Give **'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'** sysadmin and public Server Roles (by the way public is there by default)

4.Under User Mapping ensure your database is ticked i.e also mapped to NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM