# An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-6

I am new to ASP.NET MVC, I am facing this exception, the connection string looks perfect but still, the exception is raised, appreciate if anyone give me why is happening.

Thank you guys

**Model 1**

```
namespace MVCTwice.Models
{
    public class StudentContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Student> studs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Model 2**

```
namespace MVCTwice.Models
{
    [Table("tblStudents")]
    public class Student
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public string totalMarks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Action method**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            StudentContext studentContext = new StudentContext();
            //Student emp = studentContext.studs.Select(emp=>emp.)
           List<Student> emp=studentContext.studs.ToList();

            return View(emp);
        }
```

**View**

```
@model MVCTwice.Models.Student
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        @Model.gender
        @Model.name
        @Model.id
        @Model.totalMarks

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Exception**

[image]

**ConnectionString**

```
 <connectionStrings >
    <add
         name="myConnectionString"
         connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=LoginInfo;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Can you login using those credentials from sql mgmnt studio? I would start there.

Comment: yes I can, login to sql mgmnt studio

Comment: You are not providing a password in the connection string

Comment: after providing the password exception remains the same

Comment: Show your inner exception and stack trace for additional details. Usually inner exception explains what should you do to solve the connection issue.

Answer (score 5):

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name ="StudentContext " 
        connectionString ="server=.; database=here your database name; integrated security=SSPI"
           providerName ="system.data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Here is your code but change your database name and then add it into the web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

go to iis -> application pools -> find your application pool used in application -> click it and then click 'Advance Settings' in Actions panel. Find 'Identity' property and change it to localsystem.

please run the project if it runs successfully then good if not may be your solution is in below links.

After fixing the above step Some of you will experience another error saying "SQL Server Login error: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'"

So for this please follow below links:
[SQL Server Login error: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822076/sql-server-login-error-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-system)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47172/can-not-find-nt-authority-network-service-on-sql-server-2012

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of this exception
---> Change your name of the connection string, The name must be same like your context class.