# When I run my Asp.net MVC application over IIS Express It works fine but when i switch it to Local IIS it gives me this error

Tags: exception, connection, entity, failed-to-connect

When I run my Asp.net MVC application over IIS Express It works fine but when i switch it to Local IIS it gives me this error

System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException:
'The underlying provider failed on Open.'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYCdv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDhDr.png)

Answer (score 0):

So there may be you should check connectionstring and also please check below link

[An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40444962/an-exception-of-type-system-data-entity-core-entityexception-occurred-in-entit)