# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE' in window service

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I had just created a window service app
and it is throwing exception Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE'
I have tried to have user id and password but it does not work on it

and go through this reference [SQL Server Login error: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822076/sql-server-login-error-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-system)
and created a new user on that database but again that exception

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

there is solution related to my problem 
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/10/cannot-open-database-requested-by-login.html

Answer (score 1):

Are your service and the service running on the same machine? If they are not it is not the same 'LOCAL SERVICE' user on both machine and it will not work. If they ARE on the same machine using this connection string with no username or password:

Server=localhost;1433;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;

Comment: dear Noah i am using this following app.config file

Comment: code:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key ="Mode" value ="Daily"/>
    <add key ="ScheduledTime" value ="02:00 PM"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataContext" connectionString="Data Source=SQL\LOCALHOST;Initial Catalog=#####;User ID=sa;Password=######; Trusted_Connection=True;Connect Timeout=60" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

Comment: and i am running my sevice on same local machine

Answer (score 0):

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(local);Database=Main_DB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True",
```

for .Net 7.0 make sure TrustServerCertificate is available.