# Error connecting DB during the publish of a .NET6 C# Web Application on IIS

Tags: .net, database, iis, permissions, publish

I've been stuck on this error for several days and I've already tried a lot of things. I am deploying my MVC C# application under .NET6 Entity FrameWork on my local machine. I rather succeeded and my application is available from my machine.
However, whenever I try to access my DB, I get the following error:

```
SqlException: Cannot open database "COBRA_DB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'AUTORITE NT\Système'.
```

I documented myself on NT Authority and I understood that it was necessary to add this profile for permissions. I open SQL Manager Studio, I add the following profiles:
(French version but equivalent I suppose):

AUTORITE NT\SERVICE LOCAL

AUTORITE NT\Système

*(NT AUTHORITY/LOCAL SERVICE |
NT AUTHORITY/System)*
[image]

Then I gave them the necessary permissions :

[image]
[image]

However it is still impossible for me to access my DB from my local server. Can you help me, I'm a bit lost. Thanks

Comment: [Does this answer useful to you ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6894702/7687666)

Comment: already try sadly.. i have created my login for nt authority

Comment: Can you show your connection string？pls hide sensitive info.

Comment: "COBRAContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=COBRA_DB;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" (atm its local proto idk if its sensitive)

Comment: I have try to create another login "test" with pswd => its works on visual studio but not on the IIS server. I am confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you deploy your project, you could't use the connection string like `(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb`. It just for development environment.

Usually we should connect the db like below. The format should be like :

```
Data Source=XXX.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=db;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user;Password=mypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;
```

Connection Timeout=30;

[image]

Comment: I understand, but how am I going to see the errors of my database without the development mode in this case? They are hidden if I understand correctly. However, thank you for your response and your time.

Comment: @JulesValignat Usually we create COBRA_DB_Development and COBRA_DB. COBRA_DB_Development can be used for team collaborative development. The previous one can only be tested on your own machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your experience. Have a nice day.