# Cannot open database "database.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\general'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, iis, database-connection, connection-string

As I see several similar issues that I am facing, I have a bit different problem. My connection string is

`Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_new\App_Data\database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`

My application is running under .Net Framework 4.0 and managed pipelined mode is classic and identity is ApplicationPoolIdentity

The website is running perfectly but when I open visual studio and expand my database to add/edit tables, then the moment visual studio establishes connection with database, the IIS stops working and shows me this error.

`Cannot open database "database.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\general`

So I close connection in my visual studio and refresh the same page in my browser and website runs again. I want website to run concurrently when my database is accessed in visual studio to add/edit tables.

I am not using SQL Server Management Studio. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your application pool identity to run as `Network Service`

Comment: I tried with that and website runs but when visual studio connects to database i get the the following error in my website `Cannot open database "C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\ASPNET_NEW\APP_DATA\DATABASE.MDF" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'`

Comment: then again once i close the connection in visual studio and refresh the webpage i get it running and that error disappears. basically website runs with no problem, but only issue with the database when it is open in visual studio, at that time website wont run.

Comment: Give network service full control permissions to the `App_Data` folder

Comment: What happens if you run visual studio as administrator?

Comment: You need to grant Network Service db_owner permission to the database through Management Studio - you can download this for SQL Express and it'll make things a lot easier. Any reason why you're not using Management Studio? This looks like a similar issue to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251839/login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-network-service