# LocalDb -> Windows Service -> Cannot open database "" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE'

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-services, localdb

I have a problem connecting to `LocalDb` using the `LOCAL SERVICE` account.

> Cannot open database "MyDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE'.

The service looks like this:

[image]

connectionString:

```
Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

I have created the user `NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE` in `LocalDb` and mapped the user as `db_owner` to the current databases. I have also checked that the login is enabled and has permission to connect to the database engine. I have also tried granting the user the `sysadmin` server role.

[image]

I have restarted both the service and the computer but I still get the same error.

If I change the service to use my local computer account everything works. What have I missed?

I have followed this guide but with `LocalDb` and `NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE` instead.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3678481/3850405

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local Service account is not supported for the SQL Server or SQL Server Agent services. Instead, use a domain account or local account with the most restrictive permission set.

See [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345380(v=sql.105).aspx).